# Automatically Log-Out Users When They Close Their Browser in Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, browser

When a user logs in and closes the browser without logging out, I want automatically log out the user in Flex3. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Before we can tell you how to lo someone out; you have to tell us how they login.  What does it mean to login?  Usually it's just a server side session; which will time out automatically.  If you are doing something related to Shared Objects; it'd be a different issue.  If you just want to unload memory w/ any data loaded; then closing the browser will do that.

Comment: Hi @www.Flextras.com. I'm using PHP as server side language and Flex as Front end. In my application there are different levels of users. According to One's online status QC assigns some job online. I just want to update user's online/offline status when he closes the browser automatically. Flex calling PHP service but its not getting any response. DB is not getting updated. There is no concept of sharing objects.

Comment: kumar Pavuturi By Shared Objects; I meant Flash Player Shared Objects; which is in essence the Flash version of a cookie.  It sounds to me like you want to run code when the server side session times out.  I imagine PHP supports that option somehow without having to do anything in thebrowser or in Flex.

Answer (score 5):

I think the reliable solution is on a server side. For example client pings server every period of time (say every half a minute) and if there wasn't ping for a minute server logs out the user.

Comment: To add to this, I normally use a session id string for php calls which then updates the timestamp in the DB.  IF the timestamp > 15 min, log out.  I also add a 15 min logout on the client (if the user hasn't done anything) to lock the screen and not let 'intruders' see information they weren't meant to.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event and having that call something that is wired up via [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) which then does the logout.  This may or may not work, though.  It is pretty quick to get working, though, so it will be easy to test.

Comment: +1 Should probably use this together with @Constantiner's solution as a backup just in case the timing doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching on the internet and you can achieve this using flex in combination with javascript. Have a look at this thread:

http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=748226

I cannot guarantee this will work since I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Hi @Michiel Standaert, thanks for answering. Here I am not getting where should I register `ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFlexFunction",cleanUp);` . Can you please have a look at the link you've given please.

Comment: just add that to the constructor of the class you want to call it from :)

Comment: Better Improvement @Michiel Standaert but the required web service is being called but before getting result event the session is being closed. Even the online status of the user is nt updated in the database. Any idea?

Comment: then i would suggest using a server-side language to log the user out (php for example) they will keep working even after the browser has been closed, since they operate on the server itself.

Comment: I am using PHP as my server-side language @Michiel Standaert and I'm getting falut code details as **Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL (abcd.com/public/SecurityService.php?wsdl)**

Comment: I am not a php specialist, only as3. I suggest you ask a new question or edit this question so php developers can take a look at your problem.